# React map adding background color special elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I use map but I have one problem I am trying to set the background of a certain element inside the map, in my case it is "item .title" I want my element to look like this https://ibb.co/ccJzD6g as you can see in the picture background color " 100% "which I specifically set in the console for  but in fact if I set" background: orange "for the sidebar_list class, then the color will be applied to all elements including the rest , https://ibb.co/ZBTX3hd and if I set the background for the titleName class it looks like this https://ibb.co/84RKBBw but I want it to look like this https://ibb.co/ccJzD6g how do i solve this problem?

**Lesson.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import less from "./css/lesson.module.css";
import "./css/betaLesson.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { Navbar } from "../../../Navbar/Navbar";

export class Lessons extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            indexDescription: 0,
        }
    }

    render() {
        const listLessons = this.props.lesson.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                    <li key={index} className={less.sidebar_list} onClick={() => {
                        this.setState({ indexDescription: index })
                    }}>
                        <div>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon className={less.item_icon} icon={item.iconName} />
                        </div>

                        <div style={{background: "orange"}} className={less.titleName}>
                            <p>{item.title}</p>
                        </div>

                        <div className={less.titleName}>
                            <p>{item.titleName}</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
            );
        });

        return (
            <>
                <div className="abc">
                    <Navbar color="blue" bg="tomato" centerFlexNavbarContainer="flex"
                            navbarSearchPage="Search" navbarHomePage="Home" centerHeadlineNavbarColumn="center" />
                    <div className={less.wrapper}>

                        <div>
                            <div className={less.sidebar}>
                                <div>
                                    <ul>
                                        {listLessons}
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className={less.main_content}>
                            <div className={less.main_inside_content}>
                                <div className={less.header}>
                                    <div>
                                        <h2>JavaScript JSON Reference</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className={less.info}>
                                    <div className={less.description}>
                                        <p>
                                            {
                                                this.props.lesson[this.state.indexDescription]["description"]
                                            }
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First question answer: Create a new component with its own attributes separately and map/passdown the properties to the component.

Here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-hopper-2st8g?file=/src/Lesson.js